# Sum values in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I just have no idea how to sum and echo values in multidimensional array. This is my array with info about order.

I need to sum **RESULT_VALUE** and echo one united **DESCR** list. I have tried lots of things but nothing, never worked with that kind of arrays levels. This is an array with two different products with applied discounts.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ORDER_ID] => 35
            [DISCOUNT_ID] => 18
            [ORDER_COUPON_ID] => 0
            [COUPON_ID] => 
            [RESULT] => Array
                (
                    [BASKET] => Array
                        (
                            [617] => Array
                                (
                                    [RULE_ID] => 248
                                    [APPLY] => Y
                                    [RULE_DESCR_ID] => 248
                                    [ACTION_BLOCK_LIST] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 0
                                        )

                                    [DESCR_DATA] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [TYPE] => 2
                                                    [VALUE] => 10
                                                    [VALUE_TYPE] => P
                                                    [VALUE_ACTION] => D
                                                    [RESULT_VALUE] => 229.905
                                                    [RESULT_UNIT] => RUB
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [DESCR] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => discount 10% (229.91 rub.)
                                        )

                                    [DESCR_ID] => 248
                                    [BASKET_ID] => 617
                                    [MODULE] => catalog
                                    [PRODUCT_ID] => 10109
                                )

                            [618] => Array
                                (
                                    [RULE_ID] => 249
                                    [APPLY] => Y
                                    [RULE_DESCR_ID] => 249
                                    [ACTION_BLOCK_LIST] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 0
                                        )

                                    [DESCR_DATA] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [TYPE] => 2
                                                    [VALUE] => 10
                                                    [VALUE_TYPE] => P
                                                    [VALUE_ACTION] => D
                                                    [RESULT_VALUE] => 70.796
                                                    [RESULT_UNIT] => RUB
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [DESCR] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => discount 10% (70.80 rub.)
                                        )

                                    [DESCR_ID] => 249
                                    [BASKET_ID] => 618
                                    [MODULE] => catalog
                                    [PRODUCT_ID] => 10054
                                )

                        )

                )

            [ACTION_BLOCK_LIST] => 1
        )
```

Comment: _I have tried lots of things but nothing, never worked_ Did you? There are numerous similar questions here on SO: [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053492/sum-the-values-of-two-associative-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-php), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138395/sum-values-of-multidimensional-array-by-key-without-loop), [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821948/in-php-find-duplicate-entry-in-a-multi-dimensional-array-then-sum-the-values-in)

Comment: What do you mean with *echo one united DESCR list* there is no key in the array with only "DESCR" or "DESCR list"

Comment: @Andreas, I mean I need to echo cell with key DESCR and it should look like this: <li>discount 10%....</li> <li>discount 10%....</li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**array_walk_recursive**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to get result. Code below sum all values of key $key wherever they are in the array

```
$key = 'RESULT_VALUE';
$sum = 0;
array_walk_recursive ($array, 
         function($v, $k, $key) use (&$sum) { 
             if($k === $key) { $sum += $v;}}, 
         $key);

echo $sum;
```

Comment: Thanks, its worked not corretly, for example I made this to watch values.
`$key = 'RESULT_VALUE';
$sum = 0;
array_walk_recursive ($res[ORDER][0], 
         function($v, $k, $key) use (&$sum) { 
            if($k == $key) { echo $k."-".$v."<br>";}},
         $key);

echo $sum;
echo "<p></p>";`
And what we got:
_00-0
RESULT_VALUE-229.905
0-discount 10% (229.91 rub.)
0-0
RESULT_VALUE-70.796
0-discount 10% (70.80 rub.)
0_

Comment: Oh, it works when I change a conditions, for example if($k == $key && $k !== 0), why condition in your answer is includes a cells with 0 key?

Comment: Because php cast string to zero when comparing with int - write f($k === $key

Answer (score -1):

You can use array_sum and array_column.

Array_column grabs all values from one column in the array, and array_sum... Sums it...

```
echo array_sum(array_column($arr, "RESULT_VALUE"));
```

Comment: Error invert array_column parameters

Comment: Thanks! I'll fix it.

Comment: @Hazzy, I assumed you would change `$arr` to your array name. Did you do that?

Comment: @Andreas, of course, `echo array_sum(array_column($res, "RESULT_VALUE"));
print_r(array_column($res["ORDER"], "DESCR"));` Array is empty too.

Answer (score -1):

```
Echo array_sum(array_column($array, 'RESULT_VALUE'));
```

This solution work ?